# Using SSL for Client/Server communication over TCP/IP sockets without a web server

Tags: .net, security, sockets, ssl, communication

I have a server application using a TCP listener mechanism with SSL over it using SslStream class, very much similar to what is described in this thread: [Tcpip listener sockets SSL streams so much confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084846/tcpip-listener-sockets-ssl-streams-so-much-confusion)

Our clients, however, are mobile devices of all OS's (iOS, Android etc). I have a server side certificate, but all I really want from my clients as authentication is a user/pwd string pair given with Basic Authentication protocol.

If the initial connection from the client provides me with these credentials, all is well - I parse the request, extract them and do my checks. If however they are not supplied - how do I ask for them?

Comment: If you're "without a webserver" then there's no HTTP stack, ergo no such thing as "basic authentication" please clarify your question.

Comment: The HTTP(S) request is sent over the TCP/IP connection, and as I said in my question, I do the parsing and extracting myself when the user/pwd is sent (in the form of Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== for example).

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP status code 401 along with the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header is used to prompt the HTTP client to send the username/password string as can be seen in this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Client request (no authentication):

```
GET /private/index.html HTTP/1.11
Host: localhost
```

Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Server: HTTPd/1.0
Date: Sat, 27 Nov 2004 10:18:15 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secure Area"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 311

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Error</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized.</H1></BODY>
</HTML>
```

Client request (user name "Aladdin", password "open sesame"):

```
GET /private/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```